# Problem with SSD MobileNet V2 FPNLite 320x320 conversion for Coral AI TPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, google-coral, tensorflow-model-garden

I'm trying to run Tensorflow model lite on Rasperry PI with Coral TPU.
Model is SSD Mobile Net 2. It works fine on PC after conversion either fully quantized or with float I/O.
However when I run it on Coral TPU I got a lot of wrong result. Usually it is false positive class 0 (mapped to person).
Could somebody help me, I run out ideas how to fix it?

Tensorflow version: 2.5.0

Tensorflow Lite version: 2.5.0

Steps I did:

1. Download the model: http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/tf2/20200711/ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_320x320_coco17_tpu-8.tar.gz
2. I changed input resize layer to 320x320, but the result is the same as original 300x300.
3. I converted saved model to tf lite friendly format:

```
python3 object_detection/export_tflite_graph_tf2.py --pipeline_config_path /home/pawel/proj/net_models/ssd_mobilenet_v2_320x320_coco17_tpu-8-init/pipeline.config --trained_checkpoint_dir /home/pawel/proj/net_models/ssd_mobilenet_v2_320x320_coco17_tpu-8-init/checkpoint --output_directory /home/pawel/proj/net_models/ssd_mobilenet_v2_320x320_coco17_tpu-8-fixed-input
```

4. Model convertion to TF Lite format, *model_path points* to the previous step output, I tried *quantize* True/False and the commented part of the code below:

```
 converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(model_path)
    if quantize:
        # converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
        # converter.representative_dataset = representative_data_gen
        # converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
        # converter.inference_input_type = tf.uint8
        # converter.inference_output_type = tf.uint8

        converter.representative_dataset = representative_data_gen
        converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
        converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8, tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]
        converter.inference_input_type = tf.uint8
        converter.inference_output_type = tf.uint8
        converter.allow_custom_ops = True

        print(converter.experimental_new_quantizer)  # outputs True
        print(converter.experimental_new_converter)  # outputs True
    else:
        converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]
        converter.optimizations = []

    tflite_model = converter.convert()

    with open(lite_model_path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(tflite_model)
```

Data provider, used code from step 5:

```
def representative_data_gen():
    from cocodataset import CocoDataSet
    coco = CocoDataSet(input_size, input_size)
    images = coco.get_calibration_dataset(500)
    for img in images:
        yield [img]
```

5. Repressentative data set - Coco 2017 valuation data - 500 samples.

```
 class CocoDataSet:
  ...
    def get_calibration_dataset(self, limit: int):
        with open(self.annotation_file, 'r') as f:
            annotations = json.load(f)
        image_info = annotations['images']
        random.shuffle(image_info)
        image_info = image_info[:limit]
        image_paths = []
        for img in image_info:
            image_path = self.image_dir + img['file_name']
            image_paths.append(image_path)

        print(f"{limit} images will be returned")
        images = []
        fl = True
        for i, path in enumerate(image_paths):
            print(f"Loading {i}/{len(image_paths)}:" + path)
            image = cv.imread(path)
            image = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

            tensor = np.zeros((self.input_height, self.input_width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
            _, _, channel = tensor.shape

            h, w, _ = image.shape
            scale = min(self.input_width / w, self.input_height / h)
            w, h = int(w * scale), int(h * scale)
            image = cv.resize(image.copy(), (w, h), interpolation=cv.INTER_LINEAR)

            reshaped = image
            margin_x = (self.input_width - w) // 2
            margin_y = (self.input_height - h) // 2
            tensor[margin_y:h + margin_y, margin_x:w + margin_x] = reshaped

            tensor = np.expand_dims(tensor, axis=0)
            
            tensor = tensor.astype(np.float32) - 127.5
            tensor = tensor * 0.007843

            images.append(tensor)

        return images
```

6. Coral AI compilation:

```
edgetpu_compiler ssd_mobilenet_v2_coral.tflite
```

7. Inference with Coral AI (Rpi). It works fine with SSD2 Mobile Net provided in Coral AI SDK.

```
   x, y, scale = self.set_image_input(self.interpreter, region)
 
   self.interpreter.invoke()        

   detection_boxes = self.get_output_tensor(self.interpreter, 0)
   detection_classes = self.get_output_tensor(self.interpreter, 1, np.int)
   detection_scores = self.get_output_tensor(self.interpreter, 2)
   count = self.get_output_tensor(self.interpreter, 3, np.int)
```

8.Input image, scaled and centered:

```
def set_image_input(self, interpreter: tflite.Interpreter, image: np.ndarray) -> (int, int, float):
        self.did = self.did + 1
        width, height = (self.input_height, self.input_width)
        stretch = False
        if stretch:
            h, w, _ = (self.input_height, self.input_width, 1)
        else:
            h, w, _ = image.shape

        cv.imwrite(f"{self.logs_dir}/image{self.did}.png", image)
        scale = min(width / w, height / h)
        w, h = int(w * scale), int(h * scale)
        tensor = self.input_tensor(interpreter)
        tensor.fill(0)
        _, _, channel = tensor.shape

        image = cv.resize(image.copy(), (w, h), interpolation=cv.INTER_LINEAR)

        reshaped = image
        if tensor.dtype == np.float32:
            reshaped = reshaped * (1.0/255) - 1
        margin_x = (self.input_width - w) // 2
        margin_y = (self.input_height - h) // 2
        tensor[margin_y:h + margin_y, margin_x:w + margin_x] = reshaped

        return margin_x, margin_y, scale
```

9. Getting output tensor:

```
 def get_output_tensor(self, interpreter: tflite.Interpreter, index: int, result_type=np.float):
    output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()[index]
    quantization = output_details['quantization']
    dtype = output_details['dtype']
    tf_index = output_details['index']
    tensor = np.squeeze(interpreter.get_tensor(tf_index))
    if quantization != (0, 0):
        input_scale, input_zero_point = quantization
        tensor = (tensor.astype(np.float32) - input_zero_point) * input_scale
    if tensor.dtype != result_type:
        tensor = tensor.astype(result_type)
    return tensor
```

What I noticed that the results differs a little when I run the conversion a couple of times - the representative data is randomly obtained from the set. The differences are much more visible on Coral AI compiled model, that that I run on PC.

Answer (score 0):

The accuracy quantized SSD model is slightly lowered than the float model, you can probably try the efficient-det model: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/api_docs/python/tflite_model_maker/object_detector

Answer (score 0):

It looks that the newest update of Coral compiler and RaspberryPI runtime solved the issue.

RPI runtime after update: 2.5.0.post1

Edge CPU compiler after update: 16.0.384591198

Some example detections (class, score):

Coral:

```
[(0, 0), (1, 0.7210485935211182), (0, 0), (1, 0.6919153332710266), (1, 0.7428985834121704), (1, 0.8485066890716553), (24, 0.6919153332710266)]
```

TF Lite - CPU:

```
[(0, 0), (1, 0.7210485935211182), (0, 0), (1, 0.6919153332710266), (1, 0.7356152534484863), (1, 0.8412233591079712), (24, 0.7028403282165527)]
```

TF CPU:

```
[(0, 0), (1, 0.75359964), (0, 0), (1, 0.7409908), (1, 0.7797077), (1, 0.8114069), (24, 0.750371)]
```